# simulate a link call using php code

Tags: php, html, curl

i create a link, in html page, that when it is clicked, it calls a URL to another site, that cause the other site to send a response to a different URL (doesnt matter which one).

i create the html link like this:

```
print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
```

then when i click the link, the other site sends the response ok.

now i need to do the above link call , but in php code, which i believe, means call a GET request using curl?

i tried it so many times but i can't seem to make it work like the link click above.
This is my code:

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

```
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 0,
    CURLOPT_URL => $authUrl,
```

))
$result = curl_exec($curl);

$GLOBALS['log']->fatal("error = " . curl_error($curl));

curl_close($curl);

but it doesn't work and the other site doesn't respond.

i get 1 as a result.

did i call the link ok? 
is it exactly like clicking on the link in the first example?

Comment: Just to clerify: Are you simply trying to retrieve the response from another website?

Comment: just a comment: you shouldn't be using PHP to output HTML like that. Just do `<a class="login" href="<?php echo $authUrl ?>">Connect Me</a>`

Comment: What is `$authUrl`? Is it a complete URL with `http://`? Or is it something like `/posts/hello-cats`?

Comment: thanks guys. the link is: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https......" and it includes a return link that is called when i use the html link click but not called when i call with curl...

Answer (score 0):

I use Goutte for that kind of problem.  See this repository: https://github.com/fabpot/goutte

It can fill forms or click links and buttons and may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
```

Otherwise the page content is not returned.

Comment: i tried "TRUE" and "FALSE", it is not the same as a click on a link, because i dont get the response from the other site while clicking the link does work.

Comment: Share the URL, so we can help you more